# Install Mageplaza Social Login module though composer.json file

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, magento2.4

We are trying to install Mageplaza Social login from composer.json file but got error message.
We are using Magento 2.4.4, PHP Version - 8.1 , MySQL - 8 and Composer version -2.

We are try to add below line in composer.json file.
"mageplaza/magento-2-social-login": "4.1.3",

But still got below error message, we can't run composer command on server. We can push file on server.

Error message:

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- facebook/graph-sdk[5.4.0, ..., 5.7.0] require php ^5.4|^7.0 -> your php version (8.1.0) does not satisfy that requirement.
- mageplaza/magento-2-social-login 4.1.3 requires hybridauth/hybridauth ^2.14.0 -> satisfiable by hybridauth/hybridauth[v2.14.0, ..., v2.18.0].
- hybridauth/hybridauth[v2.14.0, ..., v2.18.0] require facebook/graph-sdk ^5.4 -> satisfiable by facebook/graph-sdk[5.4.0, ..., 5.7.0].
- Root composer.json requires mageplaza/magento-2-social-login 4.1.3 -> satisfiable by mageplaza/magento-2-social-login[4.1.3].

Please help.

Regards,
Prakash

Answer (score 0):

You can see in "require php ^5.4|^7.0" that the module doesn't (yet) support PHP 8.x.

Open a support ticket with the Mageplaza folks to see when they're planning on adding 8.x support.

Answer (score 0):

Mageplaza social login module doens't support php8.

Answer (score 0):

Mageplaza social login module and other dependencies composing like graph-sdk[5.4.0, ..., 5.7.0] doesn't support php8.

What you can do is ask Mageplaza Support and fix it or install manually the module to forcefully install the module. Please Note: It's not a good approach later it can create issues in your application.